# Pass network credentials by .net remoting

Tags: .net, remoting, credentials

How I can pass my NetworkCredendials by .Net Remoting? Is it possible?

I've a service (TeamFoundationServer) where need a authorize using user's NetworkCredentials. In past, I had used open User/Password pair, but for security reason at now it is not good. 
Problem is that NetworkCredentials is not serializable, and I can't pass it as parameter in some method. 
Maybe exist other way?

Thank's.

Comment: Team Foundation Server uses web services, not Remoting.

Comment: I know, but I need write some proxy for using TFS, because using TFS library get amount memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/anantd/archive/2004/02/23/78499.aspx for ways to set the credentials used by remoting.